# How do I create a page with the product categories from woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am a noob with wordpress and woocommerce.

What I want to do on my site is to create a page that displays all the product categories similar to the below image.

[image: Example of categories list I would like to achieve]

I have tried adding a page and then editing the code to have the php code to get and echo the categories, but the wordpress page builder comments out the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
The code I have tried so far:

```
$categories = get_categories();
foreach($categories as $category) {
   echo '<div class="col-md-4"><a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></div>';
}
```

Also my biggest struggle is to create a page and add php code to it. Any help with that will really appreciated.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Comment: @Bhautik I added the code I used before. Also please see me message after the code snippet.

Comment: Sure i will back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a `brands` page. then create [Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) then assign WordPress page template to page `brands` page.

Below is the example template file look like. you can give this file name like `template-brands.php`

```
<?php 

    /* Template Name: Brands Template */ 

    get_header();

    $args = array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty' => false
    );
    $all_categories = get_categories( $args );

    foreach ( $all_categories as $cat ) {
        // get the thumbnail id using the cat term_id
        $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 

        // get the image URL
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 
        
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="'.$image.'"/> 
            <a href="' . get_category_link($cat->term_id) . '">' . $cat->name . '</a>
        </div>';
    }

    get_footer();

?>
```

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. Do you also know how I can get the category image as well?